# Generate a New Spreadsheet / Workbook based on a custom template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering whether it's possible or not to create/generate a new Spreadsheet / Workbook based off a custom template has been prepared beforehand.

I would like it to be assigned to a button and displayed on my current Sheet, because I want to carry over / copy some information from the current sheet into the generated one.

Is it also possible to copy over just the selected range? For example, I selected A2:G2 then those cells will be copied over to B5:H5 in the generated one.

I'm aware of using the Create function,

```
function createnew() {
    var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("SheetName");
    Logger.log(ssNew.getUrl());
}
```

but I don't know how to have it to use my custom template as a ...template.

This is what I got so far:

```
function addnewentries() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("SheetURL");
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
 ss.copy("Copy of " + ss.getName());

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SourceSheetID'); 
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
 var range = ss.getRange('Range'); 
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('TargetSheetID'); 
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
 ts.getRange('Range').setValues(data); 

}
```

I'm having troubles on pasting the values into the newly copied template.

Comment: To simply create a template, you don't need to use apps script; the button to use Google's templates or create your own is literally at the top of the page on sheets.google.com . Beyond that, copying information, making new spreadsheets, and pasting information into spreadsheets are basic functions which you can understand from [reading the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Please excuse me for badly wording my question. I already have a template, but now I want to create a new spreadsheet BASED ON the template that I prepared previously. However, I also want to copy over some information from my current sheet to the generated one. So far I'm only aware of using the  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("SheetName");
Logger.log(ssNew.getUrl());   because I don't know how to create one based on my template.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything of what you ask above is possible, however your post is
>   very broadly formulated and addresses multiple questions.

### So to give you some broadly formulated answers:

- To make a copy of a template you can either

  - use the [`copy()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname) method - this will make a copy of your template spreadsheet and dynamically update the copy if there are modifications in the template or
  - use the combination [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues), which will statically copy only the values in the template for a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) of your choice.
- You can select origin an d destination ranges with [`get.Range()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)).
- Once you have an Apps Script code, you can run it as a macro from the menu Tools->Macros, but if you wish to create a button, you can do it with the [`Ui` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui).
- After you create a new spreadsheet from the template, you can retrieve its URL with the [`getUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl) method.

> I encourage you to try to write some code based on those keypoints and
>   post a question, when you encounter a specific problem.

Comment: Okay, I managed to get it partially working now. But I can't seem to paste the value into the new spreadsheet because won't it need a target ID? Do you have any suggestions on that? Is it even possible to grab the newly copied template's ID and have it in the script?

Comment: You can use the method `ss.New.getId()` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid